# Combine multiple conditional tags in a single function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I want to show different headers on my site. Based on the user or pages.
At the moment, I use the following code:

```
 <?php if( isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "register" or  isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "login"  or !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
```

It shows an other header if the user is on the login/register page or isn't logged in.
For the future I want to add a lot more conditional tags from WordPress/WooCommerce to this. For example: is_cart, is_checkout, ...

Is there a way to combine all that to a single function in the functions.php to use it at different areas of the site? And maintain all of that in a single function?

I have something like this in mind:

```
is_simple_header()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your function .. . Maybe like this:

```
function is_page_type($type) {
    switch($type) {
       case 'simple':
           return isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "register" or  isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "login"  or !is_user_logged_in();
           break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the function, and use a bool value as a response:

```
function is_simple_header () {
  $ret = false;
  if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "register") $ret = true;
  if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "login") $ret = true;
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) $ret = true;
  return $ret;
}
```

You can optimice these function switching to a switch() function if you only use $_GET['action']. If you need new conditions, only need to add more if's.

Your check now looks like this:

```
<?php if(is_simple_header()) : ?>
```